# Not able to view AWS Cloud 9 environment in ''Your environment"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloud9

I created a Cloud 9 environment using cloudformation template. I can see a EC2 instace created but I am not able to view the environments under "Your Environment" in Cloud 9.

Earlier i created a cloud9 environment from AWS Cloud 9 Console. The environment got created successfully and i was able to see a cloudformation template in Cloudformation service. I used the same template and created a new environment but i am not able view this new environment under "Your Environment" in Cloud 9.

Please note that i have logged in as root user. Can anyone point what what i need to do to see the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template that you reused doesn’t create the Cloud9 Environment itself, it only creates the resources needed (i.e. the EC2 Instance).

The CloudFormation template is an artifact created and deployed by the Cloud9 service during environment creation.

To create an actual Cloud9 Environment using CloudFormation, you can use the [`AWS::Cloud9::EnvironmentEC2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloud9-environmentec2.html) resource type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear, I’m happy to help.